# Remove row base on the date in query

Tags: sql

I have a query which return me below result:

[image]

Basically I am looking for the result where its compare `Document_Type` if it's same then consider recent Scan_Date and eliminate the old rows for same `document_type` in example `document_type` PRT.

Please find my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ISNULL(DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION, '') DOCUMENT_TYPE, 
    CORP_DOCUMENT_GUID, SCAN_DATE,
    ISNULL(DOCUMENT_TITLE, '') DOCUMENT_NAME,
    ISNULL(OTHER_INDEX, '') OTHER_REFERENCE,
    ISNULL(DESCRIPTIONWS, '') DESCRIPTION,
    ISNULL(AUTHOR, 'SYSTEM') AUTHOR       
FROM 
    REFERENCE_VIEW ADRV
JOIN
    REFERENCE DR ON ADRV.corp_document_id = DR.CORP_DOCUMENT_ID
WHERE 
    DR.REFERENCE_NBR IN ('XXXXXX')

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT 
    ISNULL(DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION, '') DOCUMENT_TYPE,
    CORP_DOCUMENT_GUID, SCAN_DATE,
    ISNULL(DOCUMENT_TITLE, '') DOCUMENT_NAME,
    ISNULL(OTHER_INDEX, '') OTHER_REFERENCE,
    ISNULL(DESCRIPTIONWS, '') DESCRIPTION,
    ISNULL(AUTHOR, 'SYSTEM') AUTHOR
FROM 
    REFERENCE_VIEW ADRV
WHERE
    ADRV.SHIPMENT_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT SHIPMENT_ID 
                         FROM REFERENCE_VIEW  WITH (NOLOCK) 
                         WHERE HOUSE_BILL = 'XXXXXX')
```

Expected result is as below
[image]
Where second document PRT removed as its old document ( 3/10/20) .
Please advice how I will achieve this !!

Comment: Is this query you provided is producing the result as shown ? Will there be always two records for same `document_type` and you always need to keep the latest one ?

Comment: yes. query give shown result. It may be possible to have multiple records for same document_type and I always need to keep the latest one.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  I would suggest window functions.  Something like this:

```
with q as (
      <your query here>
     )
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             row_number() over (partition by document_type order by scan_date desc) as seqnum
      from q
     ) q
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could try this: (Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=0a075bd266209971d7874c8f27b0953e) works for DB2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite)

```
WITH cte AS (
... your existing query here ...
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE (document_type, scan_date) IN 
    (SELECT document_type, MAX(scan_date) FROM cte GROUP BY document_type)
```

This assumes scan_date is defined as a timestamp. Also I'm a little surprised you only consider the document type and not the document name in your filter.

Comment: The giving me only one record which as max(scan_date)

Comment: Sorry, hopefully fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This will work too.

```
  select * from table_name
  where (document_type, scan_date) in (select document_type, max(scan_date) from 
  table_name group by  document_type)
```